# How to make SQL Server 2008 table primary key auto increment with some prefix

Tags: sql-server-2008

The given query is in mysql format. I want same query in SQL Server 2008.

```
CREATE TABLE table1_seq
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE table1
(
  id VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT '0', name VARCHAR(30)
);
```

Now the trigger

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tg_table1_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table1_seq VALUES (NULL);
  SET NEW.id = CONCAT('LHPL', LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 3, '0'));
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then you just insert rows to table1

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (name) 
VALUES ('Jhon'), ('Mark');
```

And you'll have

```
|      ID | NAME |
------------------
| LHPL001 | Jhon |
| LHPL002 | Mark |
```

Comment: Well, you need to **do some research**! It's pretty easy - [here's the `CREATE TABLE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx) statement, and [here is the `CREATE TRIGGER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) statement. [Here you find info about `IDENTITY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) (the SQL Server way of defining an "auto-increment" column). Put these together and you're done! The **entire** SQL Server documentation is available - FOR FREE and for EVERYONE - online - ***use it!***

Comment: What happens when your last id value is `LHPL999` and you want to add a new record? Also, why do you need to have 2 different tables for that? Remember it's possible to format the value on the presentation layer or in the select statement. I would go with a single int identity column and just format the value in the presentation layer to display whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

This may answer your question

```
-- create table with 'ABCD' as prefix, combining with identity column Id
CREATE TABLE dbo.Persons 
(
   Id int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL
  ,PersonId AS ('ABCD' + CONVERT(varchar(20), Id)) PERSISTED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,Name varchar(100)
);
GO

-- Do not specify calculated column when insert values into the table
INSERT INTO dbo.Persons (Name)
VALUES ('Person1'), ('Person2'), ('Person3');
GO

-- Display the records from the table
SELECT PersonId, Name
FROM dbo.Persons;
GO
```

This approach does not require to create a separate table and trigger, therefore efficient.

Hope this helps.

Comment: these are some helpful links for more information.  [Specify Computed Columns in a Table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx) and [Computed Columns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250(v=sql.105).aspx).