# EF Core: String + Int Concatenated Primary Key

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

Is there a way with fluentAPI or attributes that I can set my primary key of an entity to auto increment and concatenate a string?  I want to have unique primary keys, but I don't want the unreadability of a GUID.

Below is an example of what the Id's would end up looking like.

```
User1.Id = "u1"
User2.Id = "u2"

Customer1.Id = "c1"
Customer2.Id = "c2"

Project1.Id = "p1"
Project2.Id = "p2"
```

Comment: Add tag for database platform. If using Access or SQLServer, just let app generate a unique sequential ID. Don't bother with saving concatenated alpha prefix. This can be calculated in query or textbox.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30850328/2557128) seems useful for SQL Server.

Comment: autoincrement is database level feature, so yes, If you need something special you need to disable autoincrement in EF Core and do it in the database itself.